# How to check if pandas colums contains a value

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to check if a pandas dataframe column contains a specific string from a list and if true then put that string into a new column. I know that I possible to do it with many loop but I think that it's going to be very slow according to the number of lines I got in my file.

```
In [0]: mylist = ['ABC', 'ACB', 'DCB', 'AXR12-1']


In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
          text                  
0 ABC KEY778 20225 
1 XXX11 K ABC 14452GXX
2 ACB AZZXG112 
3 DCB AA112G AXXX
4 DCB AA15G AXR12-1
```

Result

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
          text            extract     
0 ABC KEY778 20225       ABC
1 XXX11 K ABC 14452GXX   ABC
2 ACB AZZXG112           ACB
3 DCB AA112G AXXX        DCB
4 DCB AA15G AXR          DCB AXR12-1
```

Do you have a simple way to do that?
Thx

Comment: Removed answer, because first dupe solution remove duplicated values, so 100% matched dupe.